# Autorization Code Flow with REST API "backend" on a different domain

Tags: asp.net-web-api, openid, identityserver3

We are using OIDC and IdentityServer in an enterprise deployment where at the moment we control everything (OP, clients, resources, users).

We have an SPA client that connects to its "own" API and will go through it for **everything** it requires to do. They are however being served from two different domains. (Let's say the application runs on "my.apps/app" and the API in "my.apis/api").

In our current setup, we use Implicit Flow to have the user authenticated in the SPA and then call the API and verify the token within it. This works very well.
We treat our API as a "resource" even though we don't need to and we don't require the user to give consent.

As mentioned, the SPA needs to go through the API for everything it does and this also includes augmenting user properties upon authentication, so the client doesn't even really let users work with it without going through the API.

Given that scenario, our thinking was that we could even be using Authorization Code flow for our OIDC authentication (treating the API as a backend) and get the security "benefit" of the browser never having access to the tokens.

However, due tue the applications being hosted separately we think this would require us to either:

1. Initiate the authentication request in the SPA, get the Authorization Code in the fragment but pass it later to the API which will in turn request the tokens and have them live in a cookie or something along those lines.
2. Initiate the authentication request in the SPA but use redirect_uri to the API domain, thus giving the Authorization Code to it which will request the tokens, have them live in a cookie and then redirect to the SPA again.

Basically we want to know if this is a setup that you think would work, what are the security concerns if any, and if it would be recommended for us to go ahead with this or to keep using Implicit Flow instead (specially from a security standpoint).